# How to use group by 1,2 and 2,1 both

Tags: mysql

MY query like that

```
select id,user_id,friend_id 
from message 
where user_id = '$user_id' 
or friend_id = '$user_id' 
group by user_id,friend_id;
```

But i got multiple record for e.g 1,61  and 61,1 users . i want a single record but two user either message sent or received. is it possible set group by user_id,friend_id and friend_id,user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.id,
       CASE WHEN t.user_id > t.friend_id THEN t.user_ID ELSE t.friend_ID end as ID_1,
       CASE WHEN t.user_id > t.friend_id THEN t.friend_id ELSE t.user_id end as ID_2
FROM message t 
where t.user_id = '$user_id' or
 t.friend_id = '$user_id' 
group by ID_1,ID_2
```

Comment: case when condition is same in both condition?

Comment: @dharmendrachaudhary How can a user send message to himself??

Comment: i edit my question does the above query work if condition is "or" rather then "and"

Comment: Yea, that should be an or.. @dharmendrachaudhary

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a list of all users who was communicated with `61`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN user_id = 61 THEN friend_id ELSE user_id END) AS usr
FROM message 
WHERE user_id = 61 OR friend_id = 61 
GROUP BY usr
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2197d/12/0